# AN(C)OVA - Unequal variances even with log transformation

Tags: anova, variance, assumptions, ancova

I would like to run an ANCOVA testing the mean difference in # of drinks (DV) consumed by students in 2017 versus students in 2019 (2 groups). Groups are independent and sample sizes are not equal (7,000 v. 11,000). I ran Levene's test to check for homogeneity of the variances, which came up significant, indicating that my population variances are unequal. I know typically a log transformation of the variable fixes this issue, however, when I transformed my DV (log of my DV+1 because there were values of 0), Levene's test was still significant.

So here is my question...can I still run an ANCOVA despite this violation of ANOVA assumptions? I know non-parametric tests are an option but I am trying to account for the influence of known covariates, so non-parametric tests are not really suitable in this situation. If it is unacceptable to move forward with an ANCOVA, what other options do I have to account for covariates?

Thank you!

Tori

Comment: Levene's test is less than helpful here, because its results only tell you whether, in such a large dataset, it can detect some minimal (but possibly inconsequential) difference in variances.  *What exactly are the variances?*  (The relevant way to compare variances in this context is to quote their ratios.)

Comment: The variance for year 1 data is 10.38 (M=2.17, SD=3.22) and the variance for year 2 data is 10.47 (M=1.71, SD=3.24)

Comment: Did you run Levene's test on the pooled data for each group or on the residuals from the ANCOVA for each group? The issue is if the residuals have different variances (because residuals estimate the error term). Because of the covariates, the pooled data for each group might have different variances (though this may suggest issues with correlations between your covariate(s) and the group variable, which affects parameter inference). I also second what whuber says about the test perhaps detecting a statistically significant but not practically insignificant difference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dave. I ran Levene's on the pooled data for each group (without covariates in the model). I did also check for multicollinearity/correlations between the covariates, and all correlations were very small (<.10) and not significant.

Comment: That ratio 10:47:10.38 is of no consequence for conducting ANOVA.